# weird behaviour when use interactive rebasing to add a new commit

Tags: git

Let's say we have the following workflow:

```
D <-HEAD
|
C
|
B
|
A
```

Let's say I want to add a new commit `X` between `C` and `D`, so that it can be:

```
D 
|
X
|
C
|
B
|
A
```

so I use `git rebase -i HEAD~2`
and choose 'edit' for commit `C`, so that when the rebase gets to the “edit” commit `C`, I modify sth and then use `git add .` and `git commit`, after that I apply `git rebase --continue` to end the rebasing.
But I got the following:

```
     D
    /
X  C
| /
B
|
A
```

Isn't that I added a new commit after commit `C`? why the new commit `X` is after `B`?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate what you're describing here; also if you do the rebasing the way you've described, you _should_ only have to `git rebase --continue` once. Are there some steps missing in your description? Maybe some conflicts that have occurred with the `D` commit on rebasing?

Comment: You need to apply C first so you need to edit D and not C.When you edit at C, effectively you are adding the changes in a detached state before C is applied

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say I want to add a new commit X between C and D, so that it can be:
>
> ```
> D 
> |
> X
> |
> C
> |
> B
> |
> A
> ```

It won't actually be that at all.

Let me draw these horizontally, with newer commits towards the right, as I think this is less confusing (and it's certainly easier for me).  You originally have:

```
...--A--B--C--D   <-- branch
```

When you do this kind of rebase (or any series of Git commands that produce the result you want), you end up *copying* the old commit `D` to a *new and improved* commit `D2` or `D'` (I'll use the `D'` notation).  The reason for this is that *nothing* about *any* commit can *ever* be changed, and that includes its parent commit hash.  The hash ID of existing commit `C` is fixed in stone, and existing commit `D` itself is fixed in stone and contains the hash ID of existing commit `C`.  So commit `D` *must* be abandoned in favor of a new-and-improved commit.

You don't plan to do anything at all to commit `A`, so Git *can* leave it alone, without re-copying it.  The same goes for `B` and `C`.  Depending on how you run `git rebase`, you *can* **force** Git to re-copy these to new commits (with new and different hash IDs).  If you do, these new commits will match the originals in all ways but two:

- They will have a different *time stamp* in them.  Specifically, they will have a *committer time stamp* made by using the current time at which you force Git to make the new commit.  Every commit has two time stamps, one for the "author" and one for the "committer".  The author line represents the person who made the original commit, and when they did that; the committer line represents the person who made *this* commit, and when.  If the author and committer lines match, this is the original commit; if they differ, this is a copy.
- Meanwhile, except for the first such copy, every copied commit will have a different *parent commit hash ID*.  That's because the first such copy itself had a different hash ID, and the subsequent copies must refer back to the new-and-improved (or at least, new-and-subtly-different) commit.

If you don't force rebase to copy, though, it will just leave the original commits alone when it can.  So since there's no need to change `A`, `B`, or `C`, Git won't.

To add `X`, though, Git needs to make the new commit `X` with its parent being existing commit `C`:

```
             D   <-- branch
            /
...--A--B--C--X   <-- HEAD [rebuild in progress]
```

If you inspect your commit graph just after constructing commit `X`, this is what you will see.

Having constructed commit `X` via `git rebase -i` and a pause, you then run `git rebase --continue`.  This copies existing commit `D` to new commit `D'`:

```
             D   <-- branch
            /
...--A--B--C--X--D'  <-- HEAD [rebuild in progress]
```

If you manage to stop Git at this point (marking `D` for `edit` will do that, for instance) and inspect the commit graph carefully, you will now see the above.  Letting Git go on, though, the last step of `git rebase` is to *move the branch name* and re-attach `HEAD` to the branch name, giving:

```
             D   [abandoned]
            /
...--A--B--C--X--D'  <-- branch (HEAD)
```

Since there's no *name* by which you can easily *find* commit `D`, `git log` won't show it, even with `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`.  You will now see only `D'`.

If you don't remember the actual hash ID of original commit `D`, it will *look like* new commit `D'` *is* original commit `D`.  It's not!  Git knows it's not, because Git uses the *hash IDs* to identify commits.  The *branch names* are irrelevant: all that matter are the hash IDs.

Git uses the branch name to find the *starting* hash ID, which is the *last* commit in the chain.  That's why, in these drawings where newer commits are on the right, we put the branch name at the far right, with a backwards-pointing arrow.  Git always works backwards: a *name* finds the *last* commit in a chain, and from there, Git uses the stored hash IDs to work backwards, one commit at a time.

(When Git hits a *merge commit*, which has two or more backwards-pointing arrows, Git still has to work one commit at a time, mostly.  To handle this, these Git commands keep a queue of hash IDs.  The queue is a *priority queue*, in which a higher priority commit gets visited before a lower priority one.  What makes a commit higher or lower priority depends on the `--topo-order` or `--graph` or `--date-order` or `--committer-date-order` or other *sorting option* you give to `git log` or `git rev-list`.)